# How can I make an android app start in the background on receipt of a push notification so it can fetch data from the server?

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

I have an Android app that can receive push notifications. When the app is running either in the foreground or background then I can detect an incoming notification and perform a background fetch to the server.

However, when the app is not running (has not been started) then the push notification arrives but the FirebaseMessagingService.OnMessageReceived method is never called. Tapping the notification will of course start the app but I want the data updated before that happens. The notification is also a "data" notification as required for background fetches.

How can I cause the incoming notification to start the app in the background so it can perform the background fetch.

N.B. I have this working fine in iOS it's just Android where I have been unable to get the app to start up when a push notification arrives.

Thank you

Comment: Afaik, sending notifications from the dashboard when the app is killed / not in background memory will not give you any sort of indication, you can try checking the incoming Activity's intent bundle if it contains any key related to firebase notification. Or you can send the info. via `data` using a `POST` request which will always fire the `OnMessageReceived.`

Comment: Thank you @DarShan. My point is that I am sending a "data" notification which works fine with the app in the background but when it is killed/not running then OnMessageReceived does not fire. The FirebaseMessagingService does not seem to be active in that situation.

Comment: That's what I said, if the app is killed & you send a `data` param via a `POST` request to FCM then `OnMessageReceived` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for anyone who trips over this is that the Samsung device I was testing on would not startup, other devices and emulators worked OK. So I need to find some setting in the Samsung A10 that is preventing background startup.